# Excel: Counting illness incidents

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, count

I have a table with columns "name", "illness" and "date".
From the data, I would like to calculate the number of illness incidents:

- related dates correspond to **one** illness incident
- related dates with a weekend in between also correspond to **one** illness incident

Attached an example. The column "illness incidents" is what I want to have calculated.

[image: table_illness_incidents]

Any idea how to implement this?

I know formulas like datediff, countif, ...
but have no idea how to implement this regarding my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `related dates correspond to one illness incident`? How date `20.12.2023` is `1`?

Comment: Example: Homer was ill from 10th oct. 2023 until 16th oct. 2023. This means 5 illness days and 1 illness incident. Then he was ill from 06th nov. 2023 until 07th nov. 2023. This means 2 illness days and the second illness incident, etc.

Comment: How can you know the *illness* is the same on date 13.10.2023 and date 16.10.2023? Just because those date are consecutives weekdays does not mean the illness is the same.

Comment: I don't know, but this uncertainty is okay with me

Comment: And all the lines that are hidden are other people that has been ill? I believe you need VBA to count this.

Comment: Yep, all the lines are hidden are other people

Comment: In that case I believe VBA is the easiest. Loop through unique names and filter on that name, then loop through the filtered cells and count based on the datediff and weekday. Doing all that in a formula will probably be very hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Formula in column C is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$22=A2)*--($B$2:$B$22=WORKDAY(B2;-1)))=0;1;"")
```

The formula just check for each date if there is another previous date that it's 1 workday before input day. That way the result `1` would indicate the *start* of the illness incident.

If we filter by Homer this would be ypur expected output:

[image]

Each 1 value just shows where each illness period started.

**UPDATE:** This workaround asumes your data got **unique names**. So, if you got 2 coworkers named *Homer* those rows will be treated as a single *Homer* guy